# Send multiple images to pc using bluetooth

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, 32feet, obex

How to send **multiple** images from android mobile to pc via bluetooth connection. I made app that sends single image/file. This app uses 32feet.net and OBEX.

Here is my code:

```
ObexListener.mBtListener = new ObexListener(ObexTransport.Bluetooth);
mBtListener.Start();

while (this.mBtListener.IsListening)
{
    Console.WriteLine("work...{0}", DateTime.Now);

    // For each connection`enter code here`
    ObexListenerContext obex_context = this.mBtListener.GetContext();
    if (obex_context != null)
    {

        try
        {
            ObexListenerRequest req = obex_context.Request;
            int counter = this.TotalCount(req);

            string save_as = this.ListenerToFileName(req, this.mUploadFolder);
            if (this.IsImage(Path.GetFileName(save_as)))
            {
                req.WriteFile(save_as);
            }

        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Make a array with fitting references to the files. Send them one after the other in a loop.

Comment: Your code posted above is receiving side, right?